# Como passar parâmetros em uma requisição com o Volley

Tags: android, volley

Senhores criei uma classe Customizada para a Requisição com o Volley sabendo que essa forma é possível enviar parâmetros contudo vejo que não é isto o que ocorre o que pode estar errado então?

O código em nada difere do que encontramos na rede

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
    private Gson mGson = new Gson();
    private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;
    private Map<String, String> headers;

    public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params, Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Request.Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
        this.headers = null;
        mGson = new Gson();
    }

    public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params, Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
        this.headers = null;
        mGson = new Gson();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders()
            throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {

        this.listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

para consumir segue abaixo mais os parâmetros não seguem na requisição

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
params.put(Helper.TOKEN, "1234567890abcd");

CustomRequest serverRequest = new CustomRequest(
        Helper.PATH_TO_TIPOS ,
        params,
        createRequestSuccessListener(),
        createRequestErrorListener());

serverRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        Helper.MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Answer (score -1):

A biblioteca volley não trabalha com parâmetros para todas as requisições apenas para o POST e PUT, mesmo exemplos em que são feitas as customizações se passar o método GET não vai funcionar mais se na customização você deve sobrescrever o getUrl conforme abaixo

```
// Novos atributos 
private int mMethod;
private String mUrl;

@Override
public String getUrl() {
    String url = mUrl;

    if(mMethod == Request.Method.GET) {
        if(params != null) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(mUrl);
            //mUrl = stringBuilder.toString();
            int i = 1;
            for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry: params.entrySet()) {
                String key;
                String value;
                try {
                    key = URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8");
                    value = URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8");
                    if(i == 1) {
                        stringBuilder.append("?" + key + "=" + value);
                    } else {
                        stringBuilder.append("&" + key + "=" + value);
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }

            url = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }

    return url;
}
```

Observação, solução original
em [postada por Andrea Motto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters)